# Recyclerview not updating screen onNotifydatasetchanged

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have chat app with recyclerview, Its working fine until i come back to chat screen from notification, when i come to chat screen from notification i can send message to other user and other user can send message to me but the chat screen not updating at all whether i send message or i receive. There is function called `chatDatabase()` i notice if i comment that function then screen works perfectly without any issue even if i come on chat screen from notification. But i am not able to figure out why its not working with `chatDatabase()`

**ChatScreenFragment**

```
    public class Chat_Screen_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, ChildEventListener{

    public static final String TAG = "###CHAT SCREEN###";

    List<Chat_Wrapper> message = new ArrayList<>();


    Chat_Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_screen_main_fragment,container,false);
        setRetainInstance(true);



        // GET INTENT VALUES FROM USER PROFILE CLASS

        UserName_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Name");
        UserImage_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Image");
        UserPhone_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Phone");
        UserID_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_ID");
        FirebaseToken_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Token"); //Firebase Token of other person
        Room_Name_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Other"); // Room Name of chat
        UserLastSeen_Intent=getArguments().getString("LastSeen");
        //Sender_FCMToken = Session.getFirebaseID();







        // RECYCLER VIEW
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.Chat_Screen_Message_List);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Room_Name_Intent);
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(this);

        adapter = new Chat_Adapter(getActivity(), message);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // FETCH OLD MESSAGE FROM DATABASE
        chatDatabase();
        return v;
    }



    // FIREBASE REAL TIME DATABASE WHICH FETCH ALL MESSAGES (SYNC) FROM ONLINE DATABASE
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }





    private synchronized void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();


        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            // NOW GET ALL DATA FROM FIREBASE DATABASE AND SAVE IT INTO STRINGS THEN CHECK EACH BY ITS MESSAGE TYPE
            Chat_Msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_FROM = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_FCM_TO= (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();

            Chat_Database tempChatDatabase = new Chat_Database(getActivity());
            boolean hasValue=tempChatDatabase.CheckValueExist(_ID);


            if (!hasValue) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Chat Message "+Chat_Msg);


                    long id=chat_database.Insert_Chat(Session.getUserID(),Room_Name_Intent, UserID_Intent, "Text", Chat_Msg, Chat_FROM, Chat_TO, Chat_TimeStamp, Chat_FCM_FROM, Chat_FCM_TO, Session.getPhoneNO(), UserPhone_Intent,Random_ID,UserImage_Intent,UserLastSeen_Intent,Chat_FROM_ID);

                    //Adding Chat Data Into Database
                    Log.d(TAG,"Database Entry ID "+id);
                    if (id==0){
                        Log.d(TAG,"Database Already Has Value Of This Random Id ");
                        return;
                    }
                    Chat_Wrapper chat_wrapper = new Chat_Wrapper(Chat_Msg, null, null, null, null, null, null, Chat_TimeStamp, User_Intent, UserImage_Intent, Chat_FROM, null,null,id);
                    message.add(chat_wrapper);
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d(TAG, "FIREBASE STORAGE PHOTO-3-MESSAGE ARRAY SIZE " + message.size());
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Moving to Bottom");
                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());

                    }
                });

                }               

                }

            }

            Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE ARRAY SIZE " + message.size());

            tempChatDatabase.isDatabaseClose();
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Moving to Bottom");
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(message.size()-1);
                //recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());

            }
        });
    }



    private void chatDatabase(){
        //Database Init and Filling Adapter
        Log.d(TAG,"Chat Database Function");
        chat_database=new Chat_Database(getActivity());
        chatCursor=chat_database.getUserChat(UserID_Intent);
        boolean checkDB_Exist=functions.DatabaseExist(getActivity(),"CHAT_DATABASE.DB");
        boolean chatItemsCounts=chatCursor.getCount()>0;
        chatCursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.d(TAG,"Value At Chat Database "+ checkDB_Exist+" "+chatItemsCounts);
        if (checkDB_Exist && chatCursor.getCount()>0 && chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID")).equals(UserID_Intent)){

            Log.d(TAG,"Database Exist Chat Database");
            message.clear();
            chatCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                database_rowID=chatCursor.getInt(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                database_userID=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_ID"));
                database_RoomName =chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ROOM_NAME"));
                database_ReceiverID=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID"));
                database_MessageType=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MESSAGE_TYPE"));
                database_Message=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_MESSAGE"));
                database_MsgFrom=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_NAME"));
                database_MsgTo=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_NAME"));
                database_TimeStamp=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("TIME_STAMP"));
                database_FCMfrom=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_TOKEN"));
                database_FCMto=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_TOKEN"));
                database_LocalPath=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("DOWNLOADED_AT"));
                database_PhoneFrom=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MY_PHONE"));
                database_PhoneTo=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("OTHER_PHONE"));

                Log.d(TAG,"Value Of Database Message String = "+database_Message);
                Log.d(TAG,"Row ID of Database "+database_rowID);
                // Check Message Type


                    Log.d(TAG,"Message Type Is Text");
                    Chat_Wrapper text = new Chat_Wrapper(database_Message, null, null, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom,null,null,database_rowID);
                    message.add(text);



            }
            while(chatCursor.moveToNext());

            Room_Name_Intent = database_RoomName;
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chatCursor.close();
            boolean value = chat_database.isDatabaseClose();
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Moving to Bottom");
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(message.size()-1);

                }
            });
            Log.d(TAG,"Value Of Database Close or Not "+value);

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:  i just logout and login again then entered into chat screen from notification then its working fine. Also if i remove app from recent app then it also work but i am still unable to understand, why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your `chatDatabase` function and noticed some suspicious behavior right before you call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter. I tested in my own project and noticed my rendering also stopped if I tried to set the LayoutManager on the RecyclerView after it was already set.

You set up your RecyclerView fine with it at the beginning, so removing the new calls should solve the issue, as long as there isn't anything else wrong with the `chatDatabase` function. Let me know if removing the LayoutManager lines from the `chatDatabase` function solve the issue!

`layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I added this to check if its working but its not. So i removed it but its still not working. Did you find any other issue with that

Comment: I would verify you actually have data in your `message` list. Assuming the `chatDatabase` function is actually updating the list properly, you should be pretty set. Nothing looks out of the ordinary but since you're calling `message.clear()` at the beginning of the function, I would verify you're actually adding the data. If the dataset isn't empty, I would say your RecyclerView isn't the problem and start looking in to the database logic.

Comment: I checked in log its showing that it going as it should and other user also get message when i typed and send but not visible on my screen. If i comment `chatDatabase` function it start working fine